# How to look for Minimum Android SDK for libraries?

Tags: android

I am new in Android Development. I am trying to use these below libraries & SDK together for my project -

1. Volley Library
2. Picasso Library
3. CircleImageView Libray
4. DS Photo Editor SDK - **which requires Minimum android SDK 21 or higher**

Comment: Could you try importing them into a SDK 21+ project and see if there are any errors?

Comment: @halfer so if they are successfully imported then there will be no issues ?

Comment: if app builds properly then they will work

Comment: Each of your downstream dependencies should specify the versions of the SDK they will work with, and (although I don't do Android dev) I should think the dependency fetch process will throw an error if your SDK version is out of range for any dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

properly documented library constains some readme, in which there should be mentioned minimal API lvl. if not you can check this out in `build.gradle` file (app lvl one, not global project one placed in root of project), e.g. in [HERE](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/blob/master/circleimageview/build.gradle) for `CircleImageView`

Comment: Thank you.                                                                                                                                         so here it is -   minSdkVersion 14
                        targetSdkVersion 29     so if I built my Project with min SDK : API 21  so it will work right ?

Comment: yes, it will work. for Volley it took me some time to figure out min SDK, but I found info in [HERE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/43950676303ff68b23a8b469d6a534ccd1e08cfc/AndroidManifest.xml). easiest way if always to implement in `gradle` file and observe is project/app builds and there is no yellow highlight warning (info will tell you if lib needs higher minSdk)

Comment: note that you can still import such lib (with higher minSdk than your project), but then you have to make some `if`s in your code and ensure that this lib won't be used/executed on lower OS versions

Comment: consider updating/accpeting answer if helpful :) good luck!

Comment: Will it be okay with you if we connect over some other site like Discord ? Because I am new in Android Development and wanted kind of a guide to help if I am stuck as my final year project is based on Android using Java..!

Comment: sadly no, I'm helping only here, I'm not private tutor for free

Comment: It's ok ...Thank you